# Create a docker image able to read a volume with a python script and compile/execute it

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I have to create a docker image that is able to read a python script from an existing volume and compile then execute the python script. I already created the volume and copied the python script in it. The volume only has the python script.
Here is the commands I used to do it (I am using Docker Desktop with Windows 10 Educ) :

```
docker volume create python-volume
docker run -d --rm --name dummy -v python-volume:/data-volume nginx
docker cp D:/Dockerfile/TD4/HelloWorld_p.py dummy:/data-volume/HelloWorld_p.py
docker stop dummy
```

I tried to build an image via a Dockerfile but It doesn't work. Here is the Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3

VOLUME python-volume

WORKDIR python-volume/data-volume

CMD ["python3", "HelloWorld_p.py"]
```

And then I used these commands to build and run a container of the new image :

```
docker build -t python_p_test .
docker run python_p_test
```

There are no errors during the building process, but when It comes to running a container of the new image created, It gives me this error :

```
python3: can't open file 'HelloWorld_p.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

In my HelloWorld_p.py, there is only two lines of code, which are :

```
import os

print("Hello World!")
```

So It should display the string in the PowerShell thanks to the python script and its execution. But as I write it, Docker can't access or find the script. I think there is a problem with the access of the script through the volume.

What mistakes did I make ?

P.S : Sorry for my English, I'm a French student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path `python-volume/data-volume/HelloWorld_p.py` doesn't exist in your container. That's why the error pops up.

Path `/data-volume/HelloWorld_p.py` does exist.

Try to use `WORKDIR data-volume` in your Dockerfile instead of `WORKDIR python-volume/data-volume`

You can also copy `HelloWorld_p.py` to the image using COPY instruction without usage of volumes:

```
FROM python:3
COPY D:/Dockerfile/TD4/HelloWorld_p.py /HelloWorld_p.py    
CMD ["python3", "/HelloWorld_p.py"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct. When you do `-v` [this]:[that] so [this] becomes [that] in your docker container. So when you do `WORKDIR python-volume/data-volume` This is incorrect since there is no such folder `python-volume` inside your container. What you need to do is `WORKDIR /data-volume`

This should definitely work. Also, if you are specifying `-v` in the `docker run -d --rm --name dummy -v python-volume:/data-volume nginx` command, i don't think you need to specify volume within the Dockerfile. Seems redundant in my opinion. But have a go, this should work!

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

VOLUME python-volume

WORKDIR /data-volume

CMD python3 HelloWorld_p.py
```